# How to load multiple languages to IVONA SDK - text to speech

Tags: objective-c, ios, text-to-speech, multiple-languages

I want to load multiple languages to use IVONA SDK with SSML for iPhone.
There is no documentation for use in *Xcode/objective-C*, only the SDK itself is given and several C/java examples.

**How can you load multiple languages for text to speach with IVONA SDK for iOS?**

**EDIT 1:** see my code below

load the voices at first:

```
- (NSInteger) loadVoice: (NSString*) vox {

if(voice != nil) {
    XLog(@"(voice != nil)");
    [voice unload];
    voice = nil;
}


NSString *pathIvona = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", vox];

self.paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
self.documentsDirectory = [self.paths objectAtIndex:0];
self.path = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", pathIvona]];



voice = [[IvonaVoice alloc] init:instance withLibrary:self.path withVox:self.path];

[pathIvona release];

if (voice == nil) {
    XLog(@"Cannot load voice");
    [self setTtsError: @"Cannot load voice"];
    return 0;
}
[voice setParam:@"vol" withInteger: 99];
return 1;
}
```

trying to load multiple languages to one streamer with **(the streamer is still nil, it doesnt change)**:

```
NSArray *allVoices = [self getAvaliableVoxes];  

/**
* Here the streamer is still nil, 
* i cant find the mistake here.
*
*/
IvonaStreamer *streamer = [[IvonaStreamer alloc] initWithVoices:allVoices  
withText:[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:self.path  
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] atSpeed:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-1]];
```

Method getAvailableVoices:

```
- (NSArray*)getAvaliableVoxes {
XLog(@"-----------------------------------entered");


self.paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
self.documentsDirectory = [self.paths objectAtIndex:0];


NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[self.paths objectAtIndex:0] error:nil];
for (NSString *s in fileList){
    //XLog(@"s: %@", s);
}


NSMutableArray *pathsIvona = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSEnumerator *e = [fileList objectEnumerator];
NSString *vox;
while (vox = [e nextObject]) {

if([[vox lastPathComponent] hasPrefix:@"vox_"]) {
        XLog(@"vox: %@", vox);
        [pathsIvona addObject: [vox lastPathComponent]];
        XLog(@"pathsIvona: %@", pathsIvona);
    }   

}

XLog(@"pathsIvona: %@", pathsIvona);

return [pathsIvona autorelease];
}
```

**How can you load multiple languages in one streamer on iOS with IVONA SDK?**

Comment: Since no one here can help you, you may write to Ivona developers, I guess.
[Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/ivonatts)
[Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/ivonatts)

Comment: do you have a log of the output from the XLog statements?  perhaps the objects added to the array allVoices do not conform to the expected array of initWithVoices: ... any chance you've looked at the error ?

Comment: @john do yor comment as answer, then i can mark it. it was the correct place of issue, i have added wrong objects to the array. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps the objects added to the array allVoices do not conform to the expected array of initWithVoices: ...